# Image gallery in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am new in jquery mobile.i have an array in which i have stored images link from server.i want to display these images in a image gallery using jquery mobile.please help.Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you used [PhotoSwipe](http://www.photoswipe.com). It a cool photo web framework.

Answer (score 2):

You can use JQtouch Photo gallery plugin-

http://code.google.com/p/jqextensions/wiki/JQTouchPhotoGallery

Demo - [here.](http://samshull.com/jqtouch-r148/demos/main/#home)

If you don't like JQtouch you can used-

PhotoSwipe lib- http://www.photoswipe.com/

Demo - [here.](http://www.photoswipe.com/latest/examples/04-jquery-mobile.html)

Demo Code- [here.](http://github.com/downloads/codecomputerlove/PhotoSwipe/code.photoswipe-2.1.2.zip)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the Pagination plugin by FilamentGroup. This is especially designed for jQuery Mobile

http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_mobile_pagination_plugin/

Demo here

http://filamentgroup.com/examples/jqm-pagination/demo/